# Creating mysql account users and databases in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to build an application in Laravel, that can create database users.

But the problem is - default connection to specific database.

Is it possible to create another databases from application and create mysql account users?

I can create db by this statement

```
DB::statement('create database test_db');
```

But i can't add collate and character set in this. Also can't create users.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect a particular Model to a different Database Connection by specifying the `connection` property.

```
protected $connection = 'connection-name';
```

You can check the Database Connection at [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe i'm not enough clear (my english is poor). I need to create a mysql users (as `CREATE USER` command in mysql), not a regular application users.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i did something wrong. Maybe got some syntax errors.

I did it with

```
DB::statement('CREATE DATABASE test_db COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci CHARACTER SET utf8mb4');
```

And

```
DB::statement("CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';");
```